# Avoid multiple equip item

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In the InventoryUIDetails class, in the SetItem function, we are adding a listener to the itemInteractButton's onClick event.

Every time I select an item in the inventory, it will add an additional listener. This means that clicking log potion multiple times and then clicking 'Drink' (button) will drink multiple log potions.

Where should I call the RemoveAllListeners() to ensure it is the only function that is called when clicking the interact button.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class InventoryUIDetails : MonoBehaviour {

    Item item;
    Button selectedItemButton, itemInteractButton;
    Text itemNameText, itemDescriptionText, itemInteractButtonText; 

    public Text statText;

    void Start() {
        itemNameText = transform.Find ("Item_Name").GetComponent<Text> ();
        itemDescriptionText = transform.Find ("Item_Description").GetComponent<Text> ();
        itemInteractButton = transform.GetComponentInChildren<Button> ();
        itemInteractButtonText = itemInteractButton.GetComponentInChildren<Text>();
        gameObject.SetActive (false);
    }

    public void SetItem(Item item, Button selectedButton) {
        gameObject.SetActive (true);

        statText.text = "";
        if (item.Stats != null) {
            foreach(BaseStat stat in item.Stats) {
                statText.text += stat.StatName + ": " + stat.BaseValue + "\n";
            }
        }

        itemInteractButton.onClick.RemoveAllListeners ();

        this.item = item;
        selectedItemButton = selectedButton;
        itemNameText.text = item.ItemName;
        itemDescriptionText.text = item.Description;
        itemInteractButtonText.text = item.ActionName;

        itemInteractButton.onClick.AddListener (OnItemInteract);
    }

    public void OnItemInteract() {
        if (item.ItemType == Item.ItemTypes.Consumable) {
            InventoryController.Instance.ConsumeItem (item);
            Destroy (selectedItemButton.gameObject);
        } else if (item.ItemType == Item.ItemTypes.Weapon) {
            InventoryController.Instance.EquipItem (item);
            Destroy (selectedItemButton.gameObject);
        }

        item = null;
        gameObject.SetActive (false);
    }
}
```

**On this class, SetItem called.**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class InventoryController : MonoBehaviour {

    public static InventoryController Instance { get; set; }
    public PlayerWeaponController playerWeaponController;
    public ConsumableController consumableController;
    public InventoryUIDetails inventoryDetailsPanel;
    public List<Item> playerItems = new List<Item> ();

    void Start() {

        if (Instance != null && Instance != this)
            Destroy (gameObject);
        else
            Instance = this;

        playerWeaponController = GetComponent<PlayerWeaponController> ();
        consumableController = GetComponent<ConsumableController> ();

        GiveItem ("Kampilan");
        GiveItem ("potion_log");
    }

    public void GiveItem(string itemSlug) {
        Item item = ItemDatabase.Instance.GetItem (itemSlug);
        playerItems.Add(item);
        Debug.Log (playerItems.Count + " items in inventory. Added: " + itemSlug);
        UIEventHandler.ItemAddedToInventory (item);
    }

    public void SetItemDetails(Item item, Button selectedButton) {
        inventoryDetailsPanel.SetItem (item, selectedButton);
    }

    public void EquipItem(Item itemToEquip) {
        playerWeaponController.EquipWeapon (itemToEquip);
    }

    public void ConsumeItem(Item itemToConsume) {
        consumableController.ConsumeItem (itemToConsume);
    }
}
```

Comment: When does `SetItem` get called? You need to only add listeners for click events once, I'd do it upon instantiation. What's the difference between selecting the button and clicking on it?

Comment: So looking at this a little more closely, it looks like you have a single button here which when you want to assign a consumable to it you call `SetItem`, then when the user clicks the consumable is used and the item in the slot is removed. Why not just add the click listener in `Start` and just check if an item is available in the slot in the click event? You wouldn't need to add/remove listeners on the fly.

Comment: @Charleh do you mean like this? https://pastebin.com/kw7znawt

Comment: Yes, that should avoid the issue. Still, the code looks ok considering you remove all listeners but I don't really use unity so would have to look at the docs to figure out where the original code might be going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider add the listener only once

```
public class InventoryUIDetails : MonoBehaviour {

    void Start() {
        ...
        itemInteractButton.onClick.AddListener (OnItemInteract);
    }

    void OnDestroy() {
        itemInteractButton.onClick.RemoveListener (OnItemInteract);
    }

    public void OnItemInteract() {
        if (item == null)
            return;
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: This what I did. I don't know if it's correct so please check: https://pastebin.com/kw7znawt Thanks.

Comment: I cant say it's correct, it depends on the business, maybe one day you need a feature to drink multiple potions.

Comment: What will I do if I add that feature?

Comment: The fastest way is change `Item item` to `List<Item> items` , and still add listener once.